# Inverting an IF statement

Tags: .net, coding-style, code-quality, clean-code, resharper

So I've been programming for a few years now and recently have started using ReSharper more. One thing that ReSharper always suggests to me is to "invert 'if' statement to reduce nesting".

Let's say I have this code:

```cs
foreach (someObject in someObjectList) 
{
    if(someObject != null) 
    {
        someOtherObject = someObject.SomeProperty;
    }
}
```

And ReSharper will suggest that I do this:

```cs
foreach (someObject in someObjectList)
{
    if(someObject == null) continue;
    someOtherObject = someObject.SomeProperty;
}
```

It seems that ReSharper will ALWAYS suggest that I invert IFs, no matter how much nesting is going on. This problem is that I kind of like nesting in at least SOME situations. To me is seems easier to read and figure out what is going on in certain places. This is not always the case, but I feel more comfortable nesting sometimes.

My question is: other than personal preference or readability, is there a reason to reduce nesting? Is there a performance difference or something else that I may not be aware of?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep indentation level low](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/220461/keep-indentation-level-low)

Comment: The key thing here is "Resharper Suggests".  Take a look at the suggestion, if it makes the code easier to read and is consistent, use it.  It does the same thing with for/for each loops.

Comment: I generally demote those resharper hints, I don't always follow, so they don't show up in the side bar anymore.

Comment: You should also differentiate between the functionalities offered by ReSharper: some come with the "hammer" symbol, some with a "light bulb". The former ones offer reduced typing effort in case you really want to do so, the latter ones are hints you would normally follow.

Comment: ReSharper removed the negative, which is usually a good thing. However, it did not suggest a [ternary conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312786/benefits-of-using-the-conditional-ternary-operator#3312825) which could fit nicely here, if the block is really as simple as your example.

Comment: Doesn't ReSharper also suggest to move the conditional into the query? foreach (someObject in someObjectList.Where(object => object != null)) { ... }

Comment: ReSharper is great, but things it suggests are definitely just suggestions. In reality, if you don't like them, you don't have to use them. Use your best judgement and you'll be right.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It depends. In your example having the non-inverted `if` statement is not a problem, because the body of the `if` is very short. However you usually want to invert the statements when the bodies grow.

**We are only humans and keeping multiple things at a time in our heads is difficult.**

When the body of a statement is large, inverting the statement not only reduces nesting but it also tells the developer they can forget about everything above that statement and focus only on the rest. You are very likely to use the inverted statements to get rid of wrong values as soon as possible. Once you know those are out of the game the only thing that's left are values that can actually be processed.

Comment: I love to see the tide of developer opinion going this way.  There's so much nesting in code simply because there of an extraordinary popular delusion that `break`, `continue` and multiple `return` are not structured.

Comment: the trouble is break etc are still control flow you have to keep in your head 'this cant be x or it would have exited the loop at the top' might not need further thought if its a null check which would throw an exception anyway. But its not so good when its more nuanced 'only run half this code for this status on thursdays'

Comment: @Ewan: What's the difference between 'this cant be x or it would have exited the loop at the top' and 'this can't be x or it wouldn't have entered this block'?

Comment: nothing is the complexity and meaning of the x which is important

Comment: @JimmyJames I had to read your comment five times before I could determine your position on multiple returns.

Comment: @JimmyJames: For me it is not that `break`, `continue` and multiple `return` are not structured but that the structure is made visible by the brackets and/or nesting, which I find far easier to see than keywords, even with syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Ewan: I think `break`/`continue`/`return` have a real advantage over an `else` block. With early get outs, there are **2 blocks**: the get-out block and the stay there block; with `else` there are **3 blocks**: if, else, and whatever comes after (which is used whatever the branch taken). I prefer having less blocks.

Comment: I think there are exactly the same number of blocks for either version of the same code. after all if you have an else or following code you also want it in the early return version

Comment: @corsiKa That's unfortunate.  If you don't mind elaborating on what was problematic about it, I'm always looking to improve my communication skills.

Comment: @PJTraill Clearly there is a measure of preference here.  Both are valid ways to do things.  My experience is that when I refactor code with guard conditions, I often find that there are bugs and or dead code that was very hard to see in the nested version.  This is true for both code I wrote as nested and code written by others.

Comment: @JimmyJames: There's no "delusion" - it's a simple fact that `break` etc aren't structured, within the original meaning of "structured programming" as conceived by Dijkstra et al. Whether that makes them "bad" is a different question, of course - but one of the key ideas of SP is that, if you have any piece of code K1 that, run in an initial state A, will achieve state B, and another piece of code K2 that, given state B will achieve state C, then the program K1;K2 (ie running K1 then K2) in state A will always achieve state C. Thow in a `break`/`goto` etc in and that no longer applies.

Comment: @Ewan In the case there is a single guard condition, the change in the number of blocks is small (although the change in the number of brackets isn't).  When you have more than one, though, the code is much simpler with guard conditions.

Comment: @JimmyJames: I think your original comment has a typo ("there of" should be "there is") which is probably what is confusing people :)

Comment: @psmears Thanks.  I couldn't even see that until you pointed it out.

Comment: @psmears I think you have to define what a program is here.  If K1 is a function/method and K2 is a method.  It doesn't matter if they return early or have a single return at the end:  the condition holds.  If you are talking about munging the bodies of two methods together, I see what you mean but I think it's a bit of stacking the deck.  The requirement that methods always return to the same point of the program is a key language construct in structured languages.  Methods are not simple holders for blocks code.

Comment: @JimmyJames: A program within the definition of [structured programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming); in modern terms that roughly corresponds to statements within a method body. It's hardly "stacking the deck" - this stuff comes from a time before "methods" as understood today were at all common! And it is still highly relevant even within a method; basically any sort of `return` or similar in the middle of a method body forces you to understand the *entire* control flow just in order to check a resource obtained at the start always gets released before the end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62864/discussion-between-jimmyjames-and-psmears).

Comment: *"popular delusion that break, continue and multiple return are not structured."* - It's sort like gun control, an all or nothing knee jerk reaction because there will always be some incompetents who will shoot themselves and others (poor maintenance programmer) in the foot.

Answer (score 34):

Don't not avoid negatives. Humans suck at parsing them even when the CPU loves them.

However, respect idioms. We humans are creatures of habit so we prefer well worn paths to direct paths full of weeds.

`foo != null` has, sadly, become an idiom. I barely notice the separate parts anymore. I look at that and just think, "oh, it's safe to dot off of `foo` now".

If you want to overturn that (oh, someday, please) you need a really strong case. You need something that will let my eyes effortlessly slide off of it and understand it in an instant.

However, what you gave us was this:

```cs
foreach (someObject in someObjectList)
{
    if(someObject == null) continue;
    someOtherObject = someObject.SomeProperty;
}
```

Which isn't even structually the same!

```cs
foreach (someObject in someObjectList)
{
    if(someObject == null) continue;
    someOtherObject = someObject.SomeProperty;

    if(someGlobalObject == null) continue;
    someSideEffectObject = someGlobalObject.SomeProperty;
}
```

That is not doing what my lazy brain was expecting it to do. I thought I could keep adding independent code but I can't. This makes me think about things I don't want to think about now. You broke my idiom but didn't give me a better one. All because you wanted to protect me from the one negative that has burned its nasty little self into my soul.

So sorry, maybe ReSharper is right to suggest this 90% of the time, but in null checks, I think you've found a corner case where it's best ignored.  Tools simply aren't good at teaching you what readable code is. Ask a human. Do a peer review. But don't blindly follow the tool.

Comment: Well, if you have more code in the loop, how it works is dependant on how it all comes together.  It isn't independant code.  The refactored code in the question was correct for the example, but may not be correct when not in isolation - was that the point you were going for? (+1 for the don't not avoid negatives though)

Comment: @Baldrickk `if (foo != null){ foo.something() }` lets me keep adding code without caring if `foo` was null. This doesn't. Even if I don't need to do that now I don't feel motivated to screw the future by saying "well they can just refactor it if they need that". Feh. Software is only soft if it's easy to change.

Comment: "keep adding code without caring"  Either the code should be related (otherwise, it should probably be seperate) or there should be care taken to understand the functionality of the function / block you are modifying as adding _any_ code has the potential to change behaviour beyond that intended.  For simple cases like this, I don't think it matters either way.  For more complex cases, I would expect understanding the code to take precidence, so I would choose whichever I think is most clear, which could be either style.

Comment: related and intertwined are not the same thing.

Comment: Don't not avoid negatives :D

Comment: @candied_orange You're generally not going to have a continually growing code body (remember OCP). Additionally, you are assuming a particular flow (optional branches, evaluated individually). But that is not necessarily what everyone needs. If you need sequential evaluation with intermittent early exits (i.e. "do A, or AB, or ABC, or ABCD, or ..."), then `if null continue; do;` works better than `if not null { do }`. It all depends on what you need. Synonymous syntaxes should not be decided before the specific algorithmic flow you have in mind.

Answer (score 20):

It's the old argument about whether a break is worse that nesting.

People seem to accept early return for parameter checks, but its frowned upon in the bulk of a method.

Personally I avoid continue, break, goto etc even if it means more nesting. But in most cases you can avoid both.

```cs
foreach (someObject in someObjectList.where(i=>i != null))
{
    someOtherObject = someObject.SomeProperty;
}
```

Obviously nesting does make things hard to follow when you have many layers

```cs
foreach (someObject in someObjectList) 
{
    if(someObject != null) 
    {
        someOtherObject = someObject.SomeProperty;
        if(someObject.x > 5) 
        {
            x ++;
            if(someObject.y > 5) 
            {
                x ++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The worst is when you have both though

```cs
foreach (someObject in someObjectList) 
{
    if(someObject != null) 
    {
        someOtherObject = someObject.SomeProperty;
        if(someObject.x > 5) 
        {
            x ++;
            if(someObject.y > 5) 
            {
                x ++;
                return;
            }
            continue;
        }
        someObject.z --;
        if(myFunctionWithSideEffects(someObject) > 6) break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Love this line: `foreach (subObject in someObjectList.where(i=>i != null))` Don't know why I've never thought of something like that.

Comment: @BarryFranklin ReSharper should have a green dotted underline on the foreach with "Convert to LINQ-expression" as the suggestion that would do that for you. Depending on the operation, it might do other linq methods like Sum or Max as well.

Comment: @BarryFranklin It's probably a suggestion you want to set at a low level and only use discretionarily.  While it works fine for trivial cases like this example I find in more complex code the way it picks more complex conditionals part into bits that are Linqifiable and the remaining body tends to create things that are much harder to understand than the original.  I'll generally at least try the suggestion because when it can convert an entire loop into Linq the results are often reasonable; but half and half results tend to get ugly fast IMO.

Comment: Ironically, the edit by resharper has the exact same level of nesting, because it also has an if followed by a one-liner.

Comment: heh, no braces though! which is apparently allowed :/

Comment: I will support a lack of braces ONLY when the whole `if` is expressed as a one liner. Otherwise I don't care if [Uncle Bob thinks they're useless](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/320247/131624). Friends don't let friends indent under an `if` naked.

Comment: @Ewan in C#, when using an `if` you don't need braces if the code block is only 1 command line.

Comment: i know. but its very bad practice

Answer (score 6):

The trouble with the `continue` is that if you add more lines to the code the logic gets complicated and likely to contain bugs.  e.g.

```cs
foreach (someObject in someObjectList)
{
    if(someObject == null) continue;
    someOtherObject = someObject.SomeProperty;

    ...  imagine that there is some code here ...

    // added later by a Junior Developer
    doSomeOtherFunction(someObject);
}
```

Do you want to call `doSomeOtherFunction()` for **all** someObject, or only if non-null?  With the original code you have the option and it is clearer.  With the `continue` one might forget "oh, yeah, back there we skipped nulls" and you don't even have the option to call it for all someObjects, unless you put that call at the start of the method which may not be possible or correct for other reasons.

Yes, a lot of nesting is ugly and possibly confusing, but in this case I'd use the traditional style.

**Bonus question:**  Why are there nulls in that list to begin with?  It might be better to never add a null in the first place, in which case the processing logic is much simpler.

Comment: There shouldn't be enough code inside the loop that you can't see the null-check at the top of it without scrolling.

Comment: @Bryan Boettcher agreed, but not all code is so well written.  And even several lines of complex code might make one forget about (or misreason about) the continue.  In practice i'm o.k. with `return`s cause they form a "clean break", but IMO `break` and `continue` lead to confusion and, in most cases, are best avoided.

Comment: @user949300 After ten years of development, I've never found break or continue to cause confusion. I've had them involved in confusion but they've never been the cause. Usually, poor decisions on the developer were the cause, and they would have caused confusion no matter what weapon they used.

Comment: @corsiKa [The Apple SSL bug](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/) is actually a goto bug, but could easily have been a break or continue bug.  However the code is horrible...

Comment: @BryanBoettcher the problem seems to me that the same devs that think continue or multiple returns are ok also think burying them in large method bodies is also ok.  So every experience i have with continue/multiple returns has been in huge messes of code.

Comment: @user949300 That bug is basically a bug caused by missing braces. It's not caused by `goto`.

Comment: @Sulthan I've heard the bug explained away by lack of braces, but if they had used `else if`s, which seem like an obvious "belt and suspenders" fallback for this **very important code** it would have been prevented.  Or if they had grouped the multiple ifs into a single large if (with ors in between).  Note: possibly as a separate function call!  Both of which are "more structured" than a bunch of gotos.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is the early return. Early `return` in a loop becomes early `continue`.

Lots of good answers on this question: [Should I return from a function early or use an if statement?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement)

Notice that while the question is closed as opinion based, 430+ votes are in favor of early return, ~50 votes are "it depends", and 8 are against early return. So there is an exceptionally strong consensus (either that, or I'm bad at counting, which is plausible).

Personally, if the loop body would be subject to early continue and long enough for it to matter (3-4 lines), I tend to extract the loop body into a function where I use early return instead of early continue.

Answer (score 2):

This technique is useful for certifying pre-conditions when the main bulk of your method occurs when those conditions are met.

We frequently invert `ifs` at my work and employ a phantom else. It used to be pretty frequent that while reviewing a PR I could point out how my colleague could remove three levels of nesting! It happens less frequently since we do roll out our ifs.

Here is a toy example of something that can be rolled out

```
function foobar(x, y, z) {
    if (x > 0) {
        if (z != null && isGamma(y)) {
            // ~10 lines of code
            // return something
        }
        else {
           return y
        }
    }
    else {
      return y + z
    }
}
```

Code like this, where there is ONE interesting case (where the rest are simply returns or small statement blocks) are common. It is trivial to rewrite the above as

```
function foobar(x, y, z) {
    if (x <=0) {
        return y + z
    }
    if (z == null || !isGamma(y) {
       return y
    }
    // ~ 10 lines of code
    // return something
}
```

Here, our significant code, the unincluded 10 lines, is not triple-indented in the function. If you have the first style, either you are tempted to refactor the long block into a method or tolerate the indenting. This is where the savings kick in. In one place this is a trivial savings but across many methods in many classes, **you save the need to generate an extra function to make the code cleaner and you don't have as much hideous multi-level indentation**.

---

In response to OP's code sample, I do concur that that is an overeager collapse. Especially since in 1TB, the style I use, the inversion causes the code to increase in size.

Answer (score 1):

I think the larger point here is that purpose of the *loop* dictates the best way to organize flow within the loop. If you're filtering out some elements before you loop through the remaining, then `continue`-ing out early makes sense. However, if you're doing different kinds of processing within a loop, it might make more sense to make that `if` really obvious, such as:

```java
for(obj in objectList) {
    if(obj == null) continue;
    if(obj.getColour().equals(Color.BLUE)) {
        // Handle blue objects
    } else {
        // Handle non-blue objects
    }
}
```

Note that in Java Streams or other functional idioms, you can separate out the filtering from the looping, by using:

```java
items.stream()
    .filter(i -> (i != null))
    .filter(i -> i.getColour().equals(Color.BLUE))
    .forEach(i -> {
        // Process blue objects
    });
```

Incidentally, this is one of the things I love about Perl's inverted if ([`unless`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Compound-Statements)) applied to single statements, which allows the following kind of code, which I find very easy to read:

```perl
foreach my $item (@items) {
    next unless defined $item;
    carp "Only blue items are supported! Failed on item $item" 
       unless ($item->get_colour() eq 'blue');
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resharpers suggestions are often useful but should always be evaluated critically. It looks for some pre-defined code patterns and suggest transformations, but it cannot take into account all the factors which make code more or less readable for humans.

All other things being equal, less nesting is preferable, which is why ReSharper will suggest a transformation which reduce nesting. But all other things are *not* equal: In this case the transformation requires the introduction of a `continue`, which means the resulting code is actually harder to follow.

In *some* cases, exchanging a level of nesting for a `continue` *could* indeed be an improvement, but this depends on the semantics of the code in question, which is beyond the understanding of ReSharpers mechanical rules.

In your case the ReSharper suggestion would make the code worse. So just ignore it. Or better: Don't use the suggested transformation, but do give a bit of thought to how the code could be improved. Notice that you may be assigning the same variable multiple time, but only the last assignment have effect, since the previous would just be overwritten. This *does* look like a bug. ReSharpers suggestion does not fix the bug, but it does make it a bit more obvious that some dubious logic is going on.